# Git origin/HEAD reference remains outdated and makes git fetch bounce back and forth

Tags: git

I'm seeing strange behaviours in one of my Git repositories. Soon after a clone I see this situation:

```
$ git show-ref
06e26a871527e0a5dfaffa3d01887448939fb621 refs/heads/master
06e26a871527e0a5dfaffa3d01887448939fb621 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
f9a40b7da2a67469303124a79ac79d308835e2eb refs/remotes/origin/acl
06e26a871527e0a5dfaffa3d01887448939fb621 refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Which is the correct and last status of the repository. If a run a fetch (without any commit in the mean time) I get:

```
$ git fetch
From <my company git server>:<working repo>
 + 06e26a8...c9584e2 HEAD       -> origin/HEAD  (forced update)
```

Which leads to:

```
$ git show-ref
06e26a871527e0a5dfaffa3d01887448939fb621 refs/heads/master
c9584e24b5e12338d926c1547eed3eefeca671cb refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
f9a40b7da2a67469303124a79ac79d308835e2eb refs/remotes/origin/acl
c9584e24b5e12338d926c1547eed3eefeca671cb refs/remotes/origin/master
```

If I run fetch once more, I go back to the correct status:

```
$ git fetch
From <my company git server>:<working repo>
   c9584e2..06e26a8  master     -> origin/master
```

Commit c9584e24b5e12338d926c1547eed3eefeca671cb is a very old one and it seems that the origin/HEAD got stucked there, creating this bouncing behaviour.

Moreover, if the local repository is a correct status and someone pushes changes, I got an error message when I fetch them:

```
$ git fetch origin
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From <my company git server>:<working repo>
   06e26a8..5385a49  master     -> origin/master
error: Ref refs/remotes/origin/master is at 5385a494927519644978ddfc975d4a0e94628d93 but expected 06e26a871527e0a5dfaffa3d01887448939fb621
 ! 06e26a8...c9584e2 HEAD       -> origin/HEAD  (unable to update local ref)
```

And I have to run git fetch again to get the updates.

This happens with git version 1.7.9.5 on Ubuntu machines (I tried on a couple of machines) while git 1.7.11.msysgit.1 under windows seems to behave correctly.

Can someone explain me what's happening with this repository and how can I fix this?

Comment: I tried reproducing this by changing the symbolic-ref on the remote, but that doesn't actually affect local clones unless they do `git remote set-head`. I'm using msysgit 1.9.0. Maybe it's a bug with older versions of Git?

Comment: Thanks Cupcake! I'm starting to think it's a bug, but I will wait to see if someone else has experienced something similar and knows how to deal with it.

Comment: Also, FYI, Git is not capitalized as "GIT", it's not an abbreviation or acronym like TFS, SVN, or CVS.

Comment: What does the config section for your `origin` remote look like in `.git/config`? Looks like maybe you have something in there that is causing you to push to `origin/HEAD`. Normally this is not done - `origin/HEAD` should be a symbolic ref to `origin/master` (or maybe a different branch if you cloned from a non-bare repository that had a different branch checked out at the time).

Comment: @twalberg This is the content of `.git/config`  

`[core]  
 repositoryformatversion = 0  
 filemode = true  
 bare = false  
 logallrefupdates = true  
[remote "origin"]  
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*  
 url = gitolite@<my company git server>:<working repo>.git  
[branch "master"]  
 remote = origin  
 merge = refs/heads/master`