# Error during fetching git repository on Jenkins (not each time)

Tags: git

I've got Jenkins job to run unit tests. Every 10 minutes it checks if there are any new changes in git repository. If it find some changes, it runs tests.

This error occurs every 2-3 builds. Other builds are ok.

Logs with error:

```
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url gitlab@gitlab:group/project.git # timeout=10
Pruning obsolete local branches
Fetching upstream changes from gitlab@gitlab:group/project.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress gitlab@gitlab:group/project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --prune
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from gitlab@gitlab:group/project.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:797)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1051)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1082)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress gitlab@gitlab:group/project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --prune" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Counting objects: 14, done.
remote: Compressing objects:   7% (1/14)   
remote: Compressing objects:  14% (2/14)   
remote: Compressing objects:  21% (3/14)   
remote: Compressing objects:  28% (4/14)   
remote: Compressing objects:  35% (5/14)   
remote: Compressing objects:  42% (6/14)   
remote: Compressing objects:  50% (7/14)   
remote: Compressing objects:  57% (8/14)   
remote: Compressing objects:  64% (9/14)   
remote: Compressing objects:  71% (10/14)   
remote: Compressing objects:  78% (11/14)   
remote: Compressing objects:  85% (12/14)   
remote: Compressing objects:  92% (13/14)   
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14)   
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Total 14 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
From gitlab:group/project
 + 9d4232f...2eb8fcb HEAD       -> origin/HEAD  (forced update)
error: Ref refs/remotes/origin/develop is at 2eb8fcb4a998bab10ee5851a56b61b5fc3b7bec5 but expected 9d4232f08532456b4c69a0307cdc96bd267f12b2
 ! 9d4232f..bcdc945  develop    -> origin/develop  (unable to update local ref)
   eb750cb..b4d4ce2  master     -> origin/master

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1752)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1495)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:795)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: null
```

Here are logs from a build without that error:

```
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url gitlab@gitlab:group/project.git # timeout=10
Pruning obsolete local branches
Fetching upstream changes from gitlab@gitlab:group/project.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress gitlab@gitlab:group/project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --prune
 > git rev-parse origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 2eb8fcb4a998bab10ee5851a56b61b5fc3b7bec5 (origin/develop)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 2eb8fcb4a998bab10ee5851a56b61b5fc3b7bec5
 > git rev-list 9d4232f08532456b4c69a0307cdc96bd267f12b2 # timeout=10
Set build name.
New build name is '#16007-origin/develop-2eb8fcb'
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson5005409752690042196.sh
+ echo ''
+ echo ''
+ /usr/local/bin/prove -j 3 --lib --timer --nocount --formatter=TAP::Formatter::JUnit /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace/t
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Set build name.
New build name is '#16007-origin/develop-2eb8fcb'
Variable with name 'BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME' already exists, current value: '#16007-origin/develop-2eb8fcb', new value: '#16007-origin/develop-2eb8fcb'
```

I don't understand why that error occurs. I want to eliminate it. Now jenkins job shows me fake errors (not being result of test status).

EDIT.
I noticed that when I execute last git fetch command in workspace directory by myself it returns me two different results in turns (I'm not sure if it is connected with above error):

```
bash-4.1$ git fetch --tags --progress gitlab@gitlab:group/project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --prune
From gitlab:group/project
 + c3a0c12...2eb8fcb HEAD       -> origin/HEAD  (forced update)
bash-4.1$ git fetch --tags --progress gitlab@gitlab:group/project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --prune
From gitlab:group/project
   2eb8fcb..c3a0c12  develop    -> origin/develop
bash-4.1$ git fetch --tags --progress gitlab@gitlab:group/project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --prune
From gitlab:group/project
 + c3a0c12...2eb8fcb HEAD       -> origin/HEAD  (forced update)
bash-4.1$ git fetch --tags --progress gitlab@gitlab:group/project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --prune
From gitlab:group/project
   2eb8fcb..c3a0c12  develop    -> origin/develop
```

Comment: What is your Jenkins build commands ???

Comment: It's a shell command:

`/usr/local/bin/prove -j 3 --lib --timer --nocount --formatter=TAP::Formatter::JUnit $WORKSPACE/t > $WORKSPACE/build/test-reports/jenkins-${JOB_NAME}-junit.xml`

Comment: But I think that error is before building stage, rather during scm operations.

Comment: It's the same problem as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914709/git-origin-head-reference-remains-outdated-and-makes-git-fetch-bounce-back-and-f (which wasn't solved).

Comment: I deleted whole workspace and cloned git project again. So now new builds are ok. But it's rather workaround.